# JMeter 0% error but no data

Tags: jmeter

I just test my application that insert some data to database on other machine. Until the last scenario of test, jmeter says 0% error. But when I check my database, no data there. Where should I check this thing??

Answer (score 4):

You need to use response assertions in order to test the correctness of response. Add response assertions and run the tests. At times the response code may be 200 ok but the action may not have been performed. In such cases you use response assertions.

Also verify response of your request to check the correctness of your script.

Answer (score 2):

You should be looking at request and reesponse details in the [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener. Also if your test relies on/uses [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) or JMeter Properties - you should also consider [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) or [Debug PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_PostProcessor)

JMeter automatically treats 2xx and 3xx HTTP Response Codes successful, but it doesn't check integrity of response so it is totally up to you. See [How to debug your Apache JMeter script](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) article for more detailed tips.